# Should &'s be escaped in onclick="..."?

Tags: html, onclick, escaping, html-escape-characters

I haven't found a proper answer for this yet:

**Should & (ampersand) be escaped in `onclick="..."`? (Or for that matter, in every HTML attribute?)**

I have tried running both escaped and unescaped tests on jsFiddle and W3C's validator, both are working...

http://jsfiddle.net/6LuES

```
<div onclick="if (1==1 && 2==2) alert('hello there');">Without escape</div>
<div onclick="if (1==1 &amp;&amp; 2==2) alert(&#39;hello there&#39;);">With escape</div>
```

---

http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><title></title></head><body>

<div onclick="if (1==1 && 2==2) alert('hello there');">Click me</div><br>
<div onclick="if (1==1 &amp;&amp; 2==2) alert(&#39;hello there&#39;);">Click me</div>

</body></html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: This here is totally incorrect `if (1==1 &amp;&amp; 2==2)`

Comment: @Mr.Alien It's correct (in xml/html context), but not good practice.

Comment: @bwoebi It's funny that it works

Comment: Why is it not good practice? Strictly speaking it's the *only* good practice (not that many people care, including myself)

Comment: @Mr.Alien why? how would you then escape the double-quotes if the js is surrounded by double-quotes if not by the html escape sequences?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Because it's unreadable... (readability also influences if sth is good practice I think?)

Comment: @Pekka웃 How that even works..

Comment: @Mr.Alien - Why wouldn't it work? It's an attribute value. HTML parsers resolve entity references in attribute values. This happens before that content is handed off to the JS engine. But, of course, the best practice is to not put JS in attribute values at all, but to always use unobtrusive JS.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always correct, in any HTML version, to represent the ampersand character “&” using the reference `&amp;` within an attribute value.

Whether it is also correct to use it as such depends on context and on HTML version. In any flavor of XHTML, it is never correct. In other flavors, it depends, basically on the kind of the next character, but – if it is a name character – also on HTML version and the nature of the attribute (URL values attributes are treated differently).

The short story is that you should escape it when in doubt, and normally avoid any complicated JavaScript code in attributes. Using a function call inside an attribute value is OK, but anything more complicated easily leads into confusion. In fact, many people favor putting all JavaScript code into external JavaScript files, for good reasons; as a side effect, thet avoid problems like this – caused by embedding JavaScript into HTML.

Comment: Agreed, I always put JS in files (this example is connected to a markup language I'm developing). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's valid to leave unescaped `&` in your attributes if the following characters don't complete some HTML entity. See:

```
var test = ab&lt;
```

This will be broken without escaping `&` as `&amp;` (see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ga64a/)). So, if you're in full control of your code and you're sure that no HTML entity will appear in it, you shouldn't escape `&`. It will make you code cleaner. But if there is a chance that some HTML entity may appear here and broke everything, you have to escape `&`.