# Escaping apostrophes in HTML with Spring

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring, escaping

I have an error in some legacy code and while trying to fix it I found a behaviour that I do not understand. The application is a Spring MVC application that uses JSP and JSTL. The following is a simplified example that reproduces the behaviour I am talking about. The code of my controller is:

```
@GetMapping("/users/thing")
public ModelAndView thing() {

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("users/thing");
    String stringWithApostrophe = "Any'String";
    String escapedWithHtmlUtils = HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(stringWithApostrophe);

    model.addObject("stringWithApostrophe", stringWithApostrophe);
    model.addObject("escapedWithHtmlUtils", escapedWithHtmlUtils);
    return model;
}
```

The variable `stringWithApostrophe` has an apostrophe character within it, and then I escape it and store the escaped value in other variable. After that I add both of them to the model.

My view is like this:

```
<p><a onClick="clicked('${stringWithApostrophe}');" href="#">stringWithApostrophe: ${stringWithApostrophe}</a></p>
<p><a onClick="clicked('${escapedWithHtmlUtils}');" href="#">escapedWithHtmlUtils: ${escapedWithHtmlUtils}</a></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function clicked(text){
        console.log(text);
    }
</script>
```

If I press `CTRL+U` in my browser to see the source of the page I see the following:

```
<p><a onClick="clicked('Any'String');" href="#">stringWithApostrophe: Any'String</a></p>
<p><a onClick="clicked('Any&#39;String');" href="#">escapedWithHtmlUtils: Any&#39;String</a></p>
```

...which looks good, and renders like this:

[image: screenshot of html rendered by browser]

...which is what I expected too. When I click the first link it fails also as expected, the browser console shows the error message `Syntax error: missing ) after argument list` because the unescaped apostrophe broke the javascript code.

However, although I expected the second link to work, **it also fails, with the same error message**. Why is this the case? I cannot understand it, the apostrophe is converted into an html entity as `CTRL+U`  shows, so it should not broke the javascript. I've been looking in the Internet about possible causes for this, but found nothing. What am I missing?

**Update**: I've uploaded [the example project](https://github.com/joanlofe/apostrophe_demo) I used to reproduce the error to Github, in case it is useful.

Comment: You have to escape it in JavaScript and then in HTML, I guess: `'Any\&#39;String'`

Comment: But `Any&#39;String` is a valid Javascript string, why should I need to escape it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in your question, the apostrophe is successfully converted into an HTML entity reference by the HtmlUtils class to become `&#39;`. The behavior you described is occurring because the HTML parsers resolve entity references in attribute values before content is handed off to the JavaScript engine. The entity in the `onclick(...)` statement is therefore decoded into the original character `'` as shown below.

`onClick="clicked('Any&#39;String');"` => `onClick="clicked('Any'String');"`.

Therefore to the JS engine, the two `onClick(...)` statements are equivalent.

See [this related discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16881041/should-s-be-escaped-in-onclick) discussion for more information on the issue.